# How can I debug heap errors in a C# class library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, memory, interop

I'm getting a heap corruption error in a C# library module I'm calling through COM in a C++ app. The specific error is:

> HEAP: Free Heap block 4b61bb8 modified
>   at 4b61be8 after it was freed
>   ...
>  This may be due to a
>   corruption of the heap, and indicates
>   a bug in [app].exe
>   or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

The top of the call stack is:

```
CustomMarshalers.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext() + 0x168 bytes
```

Now my understanding was that .NET was supposed to mitigate memory problems, not make more memory problems with were impossible to fix. Yet, I can't think of anything which I might be doing to cause a memory error, or how I would possibly go about trying to fix it. The particular module is using the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine .NET components to iterate VC project files, with pretty simple iterators. It's breaking in a foreach statement while iterating Files in a VCProject filter (folder), after succeeding for the previous about 100 calls. The actual code which is breaking is:

```
    IVCCollection CollectionFiles = (IVCCollection)FolderInProject.Files;
    foreach (VCFile File in CollectionFiles)
    {
        [...]
    }
```

How can I possibly go about debugging this?

Update:

When I call if from a pure C# Console app (no COM or native code involved), I get:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in [component].dll
>   
>   Additional
>   information: Attempted to read or
>   write protected memory. This is often
>   an indication that other memory is
>   corrupt.

Still no clue how I could go about debugging this. Obviously there's a memory error happening somewhere... but how can I track it down in pure managed code where the memory model isn't even exposed?

Comment: Did you build a PIA for the COM module, or did you use a pre-built PIA?

Comment: What's a PIA? I build the public interface, if that's what you're asking. I have build and used COM objects successfully before, and this one works if I return immediately; it only fails while using the VC .NET objects. Also, see my followup.

Comment: PIA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Good point about the answer/edit thing, I have updated the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It is looking like your COM interface is not properly marshaling a parameter/return variable, causing either managed memory to be free'd unexpectedly by the GC or unmanaged memory to be trashed due to some improper marshaling. You can get some finer grained control over the COM interface created by building your own [Primary Interop Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch(VS.80).aspx) for the COM component. With a little bit of work you can examine the offending method on the COM object and ensure all of its parameters have the correct metadata to ensure they are marshal'd correctly.

Now, the other possibility is you're marshaling everything properly, but you're not quite calling the interface correctly, manifesting itself as an improper usage of a parameter which eventually trashes unmanaged memory. These are less fun to track down, especially if you do not have access to the COM source.

One trick is to allow the program to crash outside your debugger, click Debug, which brings up the pick JIT Debugger window. Then check the 'Choose Debugging Engine' (or something to that effect) and ensure both the Managed and Native checkboxes are ticked. The VS instance which comes up should be broken in the actual code that died, rather than the closest managed code to the death.

Comment: I don't think it's the COM part, though; there's no COM usage in my test Console app usage. I suspect it's something to do with the Visual Studio automation classes, but I have no idea how to debug it.